# Angular button enabled if the radio button is clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I have a question.

This is a study case for my work.

[image: web interface]

From this screenshot, I need to release (enable) the button « ajouter » when, at least, one radio button is ticked in the safe boot (secure chest, where you put your favorite files used, if you prefer).

On the contrary, I need to disable this button when no radio button is ticked.

The btn ( = button) and the radio component are coded in two specific components I think, with in the subdirectories one .html & .ts .

[image: structure of the project]

From the coffre-fort.component, I have :

[image]

I need to interact with this element (p-tableRadioButton) to do a loop on the different radio btns & set a flag if the radio btn is clicked or not.

After if the flag is to true, we activate the btn " Ajouter ", is it the good pattern to follow ?

The code of the btn "Ajouter" is in another template:

[image]

In the two .ts files, we have the two annotations @Input, @Output & @ViewChild related to the child/father component, but I'm not very familiar with them.

Please, can you advise how to deal with this situation?

Have a nice day,

Comment: I would recommend a service which will hold a boolean if the button is enabled or not. Every click of radiobutton you check if it should be enabled and set the value in the service.

Comment: post code not pictures

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve it using a subject.

You must be having a service.ts already, if not create one by using the following command:

```
ng g s your-service-name
```

In your service.ts, create a subject like this:

```
public isRadioButtonClicked = new Subject<boolean>();
fetchStatusOfRadioButton$ = this.isRadioButtonClicked.asObservable();
```

In your HTML file housing the radio buttons, create a (click) event like this:

```
(click)="radioButtonClicked()"
```

In the same component's .ts file, put the below code:

```
radioButtonClicked(){
    this.isRadioButtonClicked.next(true);
}
```

In your .ts file housing ajouter button, put the below code in the ngOnInit hook:

```
 this.your-service-name.fetchStatusOfRadioButton$.subscribe((res)=>!disableAjouterButton=res);
```

This would automatically disable the Ajouter button if radio button is clicked.

Also, don't forget to unsubscribe using ngOnDestroy hook.

Comment: great answer, If he's using Angular 16 `Signals` could even be a better solution.